# fix for a reversed link

Tags: c, linked-list, insert, singly-linked-list

hey for some reason my linked list is printing in the reversed ordear for example if my input is 2->4->6
my output is 6->4->2

```
list* add_int_list(list* a,int b)
{
    list *temp;
    temp = (list*)malloc(sizeof(list*));
    temp->next = NULL;
    if (a->next == NULL)//insert to the first node
    {
        temp->data = b;
        temp->next = a;
        a = temp;

    }
    else 
    {
        temp->data = b;
        temp->next = a;
        a = temp;//I think the problem is here, couldnt find how to fix 
}
```

Comment: Hey! For some reason your code for inserting the first and subsequent nodes is the same. That means that you always insert new nodes at the front, which will make a list in reverse insertion order. (That's also not the whole code you show. Surely you return the new list head, no?)

Comment: If you want to append something to the end of the list, you need to walk the list and then add it as the last node. (Iterate through the `->next` pointers until NULL. And then insert the `temp` node at the end of the list.)

Comment: What is the purpose of the `if` statement?  Both branches have *identical* code.  Either make them different or delete the `if`.

Comment: Also I believe your code will crash if you pass in `NULL` for `a`. You should handle that case before trying to dereference it with the arrow statement on line 6.

Comment: and can i do that in the same function add to the head and to the end?

Comment: It depends on the goal of your function. You could write it to do whatever you want. But judging by your expected output, it seems like you always want to append to the end of the list. In which case adding to the head isn't really needed, unless the input is `NULL`. I put an answer that may help guide you in the correct direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters in this statement

```
temp = (list*)malloc(sizeof(list*));
                            ^^^^^
```

there is allocated memory of the size equal to the size of pointer instead of the size of the node. You have to write either

```
temp = (list*)malloc(sizeof(list));
```

or

```
temp = (list*)malloc(sizeof( *temp));
```

This if statement

```
if (a->next == NULL)
```

can invoke undefined behavior because initially the list can be empty. So the pointer `a` can be equal to NULL. That is there is used a null pointer to access memory.

There is no difference between these two code blocks after the if and else parts of the if-else statement

```
if (a->next == NULL)//insert to the first node
{
    temp->data = b;
    temp->next = a;
    a = temp;
}
else 
{
    temp->data = b;
    temp->next = a;
    a = temp;//
}
```

That is the both code snippet try insert a new-node in the beginning of the list.

It is a general approach to insert a new node in a singly-linked one-sided list in its beginning. To append a node to such a list to its end is inefficient because the whole list must be traversed.

If you want to append a node to the end of a singly linked list then make it two-sided.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
} Node;

typedef struct List
{
    Node *head;
    Node *tail;
} List;

int push_front( List *list, int data )
{
    Node *new_node = malloc( sizeof( Node ) );
    int success = new_node != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        new_node->data = data;
        new_node->next = list->head;

        list->head = new_node;

        if ( list->tail == NULL ) list->tail = list->head;
    }

    return success;
}

int push_back( List *list, int data )
{
    Node *new_node = malloc( sizeof( Node ) );
    int success = new_node != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        new_node->data = data;
        new_node->next = NULL;

        if ( list->tail == NULL )
        {
            list->head = list->tail = new_node;
        }
        else
        {
            list->tail = list->tail->next = new_node;
        }
    }   

    return success;
}

void output( const List *list )
{
    for ( const Node *current = list->head; current != NULL; current = current->next )
    {
        printf( "%d -> ", current->data );
    }

    puts( "null" );
}

int main(void) 
{
    List list = { .head = NULL, .tail = NULL };

    const int N = 10;

    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        if ( i % 2 != 0 )
        {
            push_front( &list, i );
        }
        else
        {
            push_back( &list, i );
        }

        output( &list );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
0 -> null
1 -> 0 -> null
1 -> 0 -> 2 -> null
3 -> 1 -> 0 -> 2 -> null
3 -> 1 -> 0 -> 2 -> 4 -> null
5 -> 3 -> 1 -> 0 -> 2 -> 4 -> null
5 -> 3 -> 1 -> 0 -> 2 -> 4 -> 6 -> null
7 -> 5 -> 3 -> 1 -> 0 -> 2 -> 4 -> 6 -> null
7 -> 5 -> 3 -> 1 -> 0 -> 2 -> 4 -> 6 -> 8 -> null
9 -> 7 -> 5 -> 3 -> 1 -> 0 -> 2 -> 4 -> 6 -> 8 -> null
```

In this demonstrative program even numbers are inserted in the end of the list using the function `push_back` and odd numbers are inserted in the beginning of the list using the function `push_front`.

If you C compiler does not support designated initializers then this declaration

```
List list = { .head = NULL, .tail = NULL };
```

can be changed the following way

```
List list = { NULL, NULL };
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your code is appending the node to the front of the list in both cases. If you want to always append to the end of the list, you need to walk the list until the end and then add `temp` there.

I wrote this code off-the-cuff, so take it as pseudo-code:

```
// Assuming this function returns the front (head) of the list.
list* append_element_to_list(list* a, int b)
{
    list *newNode;
    newNode = (list*)malloc(sizeof(list*));
    newNode->data = b;

    // Handle the case where `a` is NULL. This means
    // no list was passed in, so the newly created node
    // will be returned to start the list.
    if (a == NULL)
    {
      return newNode;
    }

    // If we get this far, it means `a` contains at least
    // one node. So walk the list until the end.
    list *currentNode = a;
    while (currentNode->next != NULL)
    {
      currentNode = currentNode->next;
    }

    // Once you reach the end of the list, set
    // `newNode` as the last node.
    currentNode->next = newNode;

    // The front of the list hasn't changed, so return that.
    return a;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have some mistakes in your code, I am making correction in your code, just changing what required.
first I want to focus on main issue, before inserting at last of any list, you should iterate the complete list.

```
  i = a; // to iterate
  while(i->next != NULL)
  {
   i = i->next;
  }
  // Now i is last node of list a
  i->next = temp;
```

Now the below code, I just check it on TurboC, I am using your function and inserting three values and then printing the list.
Please see all the line comments:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
typedef struct node{
 int data;
 struct node *next;

}list;

list* add_int_list(list* a,int b)
{
    list *temp;
    list *i;

    temp = (list*)malloc(sizeof(list*));
    temp->next = NULL;
    temp->data = b;

    if (a == NULL)//insert to the first node
    {
       //temp->data = b; -  done above
    //temp->next = a; no reason for this line
        a = temp;
    }
    else
    {
       // temp->data = b; - done above
       //temp->next = a; wrong logic
       // a = temp;//I think the problem is here, couldnt find how to fix : Yes it is also wrong

      //Here it required to iterate complete list and go to end

      i = a; // to iterate
      while(i->next != NULL)
      {
       i = i->next;
      }
      // Now i is last node of list a
      i->next = temp;
    }

    return a;
}
void printList(list *root)
{
   list *i;

   if(root == NULL)
   {
    printf("List is empty");
   }
   else
   {
    i = root;
    while(i != NULL){
      printf("%d,",i->data);
      i = i->next;
    }
   }
}
int main()
{
  list *root = NULL;
  clrscr();
  root =  add_int_list(root, 3);
  root =  add_int_list(root, 4);
  root =  add_int_list(root, 5);
  printList(root);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I believe there are a few mistakes in `printList`. The line `if(root->data == NULL)` is checking an `int` against `NULL`. Should probably be `if(root == NULL)`. Also in the same method the line `while(i->data != NULL){` does the same mistake. Should probably be `while(i->next != NULL){`. Lastly the printing of the list doesn't appear to print the final value. You may need a final `printf("%d\n",i->data);` after the while loop.

Comment: ```void printList(list *root)
{
   list *i;

   if( !root )
   {
    printf("List is empty");
   }
   else
   {
    i = root;
    while( i ){
      printf("%d,",i->data);
      i = i->next;
    }
   }
}```

Comment: @MrHappyAsthma, Thanx for your suggestion, I edited it.